# Angularjs: delete item using index

Tags: angularjs

Some context: I have a task list using an api to save each task to mysql.
My `delete method` is triggered by a button with ng-click (`ng-click="remove(todo, $index)"`) and looks like this:

```
  $scope.remove = function (todo, index) {
    $http({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: 'http://api.dev/api/task/delete/' + todo.id }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
      });
  };
```

This works just fine, but I'm wondering how could I make it work without passing the `todo` and using only the `index`?

Comment: I believe you need to have the id of the todo to know which todo to delete.

Comment: What is the reason for not passing the todo?

Comment: @Matt mostly just for fun, but can't I get to the `id` using the `index`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the same array you fill the list from - `todos`. Assuming you have not manipulated the order of items in the list by applying filters or using order by when creating the list.

```
    $scope.remove = function (index) {
    var listElement = $scope.todos[index];
    $http({
      method: 'DELETE',
      url: 'http://api.dev/api/task/delete/' + listElement .id }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
      });
  };
```

Do note, this is not best practice due to the fact you sometimes mess with the order of the list.

Here Is a little demo, demonstrating what I am talking about. Look the list order in the controller. Now, look at indexes after the names in HTML.

[demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZZgBJ)

Comment: I believe this will give an error since `todos` it's not defined

Comment: Right you could do it this way. You could get todos by doing `angular.element('#todos')` and tag todos with said id. Buuuuuuut, please don't. This is bad.

Comment: You are right, when I copied I cut out the $scope part.

Comment: Like @DanteTheSmith said. This is not guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: It does work, thank you DanteTheSmith and @Matt, but you make good points and I'll probably hold to my initial solution.